# undesirable empty space between status bar and custom snackbar

Tags: android

my activity xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.votingsystem.tsiro.mainClasses.LoginActivity">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<com.rey.material.widget.FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/revealContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/themeImgv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/theme" />

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginActivityFgmtContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <com.rey.material.widget.FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/errorContainerRlt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/errorContainer_Rlt_height" />

    <com.rey.material.widget.SnackBar
        android:id="@+id/loginActivitySnkBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/loginActivity_SnkBar_height"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</com.rey.material.widget.FrameLayout>
```

[image]

setting windowTranslucentStatus to true to main Application theme eliminates the empty space shown in the picture. Can anybody tell me what's is going wrong if windowTranslucentStatus is set to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after a second careful look at my code i found out that i was setting programmatically padding to my custom snackbars container layout...i removed it and empty space 'magically' removed...sorry for being so careless and post such stupid question..